# Supabase, filter by column value of foreign key row

Tags: sql, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to figure out how to implement a query in supabase:

**Schema**

```sql
CREATE TABLE cars 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    brand TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE stores 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    car INT REFERENCES car(id),
    name TEXT
);
```

I want to get all stores which carry the car of brand "x"

In Supabase I can filter like this:

```js
let { data: stores } = await supabase
  .from('stores')
  .select("*")
  .eq('name', 'Ford car shop')


// Returns
{
  id: 123456,
  car:"Ford",
  name:"Ford car shop"
}
```

or join like this:

```js
let { data: stores } = await supabase
  .from('stores')
  .select(`
    *,
    cars (
      brand
    )
  `)
  .eq('name', 'Ford car shop')

// Returns
{
  id: 123456,
  car:"Ford",
  cars: {
     id: 654321,
     brand: "Ford"
  }
  name:"Ford car shop"
}
```

But how can I filter stores by the brand of the car they carry using the supabase sdk?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

2022: This is now possible with supabase client. You can use the `!inner()` function.

```js
let { data: stores } = await supabase
  .from('stores')
  .select('*, cars!inner(*)')
  .eq('cars.brand', 'Ford')
```

Doc here: [Filtering with inner joins](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#filtering-with-inner-joins)

Comment: Good to see this has been implemented. Thanks for the update!

Comment: Just adding that if you don't want to actually grab the data, you can still filter by it with `cards!inner()` the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in postgrest api supabase gives you to get this info. e.g:

```
/projects?select=*,clients!inner(*)&clients.id=eq.12
```

this isn't added to the supabase client yet.

the patch is shown here: https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/releases/tag/v9.0.0

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
**Supabase recently added this feature. The new accepted answer is below.**

I did some more research and found out that [this is currently not possible](https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/197). However, it seems like it has been implemented and will make it into the next Supabase release.

An interim solution is using views and then querying those.

```sql
CREATE VIEW stores_expanded AS
SELECT
  stores.id,
  stores.name,
  cars.brand
FROM
  stores
  LEFT JOIN cars
ON
  stores.car = cars.id;
```

```js
let { data: stores } = await supabase
  .from('stores')
  .select("*")
  .eq('brand', 'x')
```

Comment: Yes. But you cannot use RLS with VIEWs.